# xcode 8 swift 3 image file won't upload to server

Tags: php, upload, swift3, xcode8, pic

Using Xcode 8, Swift 3 and PHP.

Xcode and PHP are running without error.

Why isn't displayPic.image from simulator saved to pic1-1.png at server?  All that appears is a blank file.

Xcode:

```
@IBAction func sendToServer(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.example.com/picSaver.php")

    var request = URLRequest(url: url! as URL)

    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    var boundary = generateBoundaryString()

    request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", 
forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    if (displayPic.image == nil)
    { return }

    let image_data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(displayPic.image!)
    var body = NSMutableData()
    let fname = "porch-167.png"
    let mimetype = "image/png"

    body.append("--\(boundary)\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
    body.append("Content-Disposition:form-data; 
name=\"photo\"\r\n\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
    body.append("Incoming\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
    body.append("--\(boundary)\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
    body.append("Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"file\"; 
filename=\"\(fname)\"\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
    body.append("Content-Type: \(mimetype)\r\n\r\n".data(using: 
String.Encoding.utf8)!)
    body.append(image_data!)
    body.append("\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
    body.append("--\(boundary)--\r\n".data(using: 
String.Encoding.utf8)!)

    request.httpBody = body as Data

    let session = URLSession.shared

    let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
        (
        data, response, error) in

        guard let _:Data = data, let _:URLResponse = response , error 
== nil else {
            print("error")
            return
            }

        let dataString = String(data: data!, encoding: 
String.Encoding(rawValue: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue))
        print(dataString)

        }

    task.resume()
}

}

func generateBoundaryString() -> String {

return "Boundary-\(NSUUID().uuidString)"    
}
```

picSaver.php

```
<?php
$p=$_REQUEST["filename"]
move_uploaded_file($p["tmp_name"], pic1-1.png);

$data=Array("Reply"=>"Image saved at server");
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Is "filename" the correct parameter request for $p $_REQUEST ?

Comment: Okay,I'll try that.

Comment: I added the php script, and unwrapped p with an !.  There are no errors, but the jpeg saved to the server is blank.  Any suggestions.

Comment: Any suggestions. @Jakub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works flawlessly now.  Change $_REQUEST to $_FILES, and "filename" to "file"

```
<?php
$p=$_FILES["file"]
move_uploaded_file($p["tmp_name"], "pic1-1.png");

$data=Array("Reply"=>"Image saved at server");
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```